# Combine values in dataframe on multiple rows on date and name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe dataset where I would like to combine some of the data. At the moment I've tried by using `.groupby()` and `.sum()` but the result I get is not what I expected.

My data set atm looks like the following:

| date | value | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-19 | 27 | podcast_processed |
| 2022-01-19 | 25 | podcast_processed |
| 2022-01-19 | 23 | podcast_processed |
| 2022-01-19 | 23 | podcast_processed |
| 2022-01-19 | 23 | n_known_errors |
| 2022-01-19 | 23 | n_known_errors |
| 2022-01-19 | 23 | n_known_errors |
| 2022-01-19 | 23 | n_known_errors |
| 2022-01-19 | 0 | n_unknown_errors |
| 2022-01-19 | 0 | n_unknown_errors |
| 2022-01-19 | 2 | n_unknown_errors |
| 2022-01-19 | 0 | n_unknown_errors |

[Image of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrXhZ.png)

What I would like to achieve is to combine the values on the different names. How can this be done?

So the data would be (In propper dataframe format):

| date | value | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-19 | 98 | podcast_processed |
| 2022-01-19 | 69 | n_known_errors |
| 2022-01-19 | 2 | n_unknown_errors |

My code:

```
from xxx.input import get_automation_metrics

def graph_visual_data(script_title):
    data = get_automation_metrics(script_title)
    data = data[data.name.isin(['podcast_processed', 'n_unknown_errors', 'n_known_errors'])][['date','value','name']]
    data.date = data.date.dt.date
    data.value = data.value.astype(int)

    data = data.groupby(['name','date'])['value'].sum()

    fig = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar(size=10).encode(
        x='date',
        y='value',
        color='name',
        tooltip=['name', 'value']
    ).interactive()
    st.altair_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

As an extra if possible, I need to subtract the combined values from `n_unknown_errors` and `n_known_errors` from the total of `podcast_processed`. So the data would look like (In propper dataframe format):

| date | value | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-19 | 27 | podcast_processed |
| 2022-01-19 | 69 | n_known_errors |
| 2022-01-19 | 2 | n_unknown_errors |

Comment: Please do not use images for values! We cannot copy and paste to reproduce...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sorry, I'm still learning to improve my Questions on here. I've updated the data now. Thanks for your feddback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default an aggregation on a groupby puts the grouping columns in the index and they are no longer *normal* columns.

You can either fix it with `reset_index`:

```
data = data.groupby(['date', 'name']).sum().reset_index()
```

or prevent it with `as_index=False`:

```
data = data.groupby(['date', 'name'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Both ways would give:

```
         date               name  value
0  2022-01-19     n_known_errors     92
1  2022-01-19   n_unknown_errors      2
2  2022-01-19  podcast_processed     98
```

Comment: So if you don't tell the `.groupby`funciton to ignore the indexes it just keeps the data as it is normally?